# Unix scripting : Writing to another file with ":" is failing

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, grep

I have below record (and many other such records) in one file

```
9460    xyz            abc (lmn):1027739543798. Taxpayer's identification number (INN): 123. For all IIB. 2016/02/03
```

I need to search for the keyword **IIB**. If it matches, then I need to take that entire record and write to another file.

Below is the code which already exists. This code is not working. Problem with this code is when it takes the full matched
record, it is ignoring the text which falls after ":" and writing to another file.

```
cat keyword.cfg | while read KwdName
do
    echo "KEYWORD:"${KwdName} //This prints IIB
    grep "^${KwdName}\|${KwdName}\|~${KwdName}~\|:${KwdName}$\|:${KwdName}~" ${mainFileWithListOfRecords} | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' >> ${destinationFile}
done
```

So, instead of writing below record to destination file

```
9460    xyz            abc (lmn):1027739543798. Taxpayer's identification number (INN): 123. For all IIB. 2016/02/03
```

It is only writing,

```
9460    xyz            abc (lmn)
```

`cat -vte mainFileWithListOfRecords` gives below output

```
9460^IMEZHPROMBANK^I^ICJSC ;IIB;~ Moscow, (lmn): 1027739543798. Taxpayer's identification number (INN): 123. For all IIB. 2016/02/031#msid=s1448434872350^IC1^I2000/12/28^I2015/11/26^I^I$
```

Comment: Thanks. But, keyword.cfg file contains list of keywords to be matched. Like keyword.cfg contains - IIB PCT DFD etc. I just took IIB as an example. If IIB does not match then it should try matching for PCT and then DFD and so on..

Comment: Nope. It didn't work :). Outcome is the same. It is printing only till ":" . Its not writing records after that

Comment: I didn't get you. Keyword.cfg file does not contain ":" . It just contains IIB DFD ect. mainFileWithListOfRecords contains ":"

Comment: Not the config file. Post output of `cat -vte "$mainFileWithListOfRecords"` in question

Comment: I have edited my question with what you requested.

Comment: ok and what does: `grep 'IIB' mainFileWithListOfRecords` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short fix is replacing

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
```

with

```
cut -d ":" -f2-
```

But what are you cutting? Maybe `${mainFileWithListOfRecords}` is a variabele with a list of files. In that case grep will show the matching file in front of its matches. You can change that with the -h option.
The result is that you do not need to cut or awk:

```
grep -h "${KwdName}" ${mainFileWithListOfRecords} >> ${destinationFile}
```

(I changed the searchstring as well, with `\|${KwdName}\|` in your searchstring you will match KwdName in all combinations)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it cuts on the colon - you programmed it that way. In your code, you have `| awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`, which basically means "throw away everything starting from the first colon".

If you don't want to do this, why do you explicitly request it? What was your original intention, when writing the `awk` command?

Comment: I removed `| awk -F ":"` and re-run the script. Even then it is throwing away everything starting from the first colon.

Comment: Can't be. Run it with `set -x` and see what's going on. Post the output.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in the redirection and are still looking at the old $destination_file? Do a `ls -l` at the resulting file and check the timestamp.